# Run job step as different user than SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I created a SSIS package and for connection with SQL Server, I used Windows authentication.

When I run that package in SSIS, it works fine.

Then I created a job and added a step to run that SSIS package. In the package in the "run as" field, it is showing "SQL Server Agent Service Account" (which is someone else). When I run the job it returns me the error "The provider is not registered on the local machine".

After some searching, I find to add the proxy. But when I add credentials, it does not accept the Windows authentication - I have to enter the password manually. But when I use that proxy it returns "password not correct".

I am new to SQL Server, before posting this I search a lot but was not able to find enough.

Can anyone please guide me how I can resolve this problem?

Or is there any better approach to resolve this issue?

TIA

Comment: I guess you are searching in the wrong place: according to your message, the problem was not that the step failed due to authentication but due to a missing service. Now, in order to give proper advice we will need to know hat your package does. E.g. does it contain data flows which use certain data providers? Did you install any provider on yor dev. computer which might be missing on the server? I had a similar problem when I had to deploy some DB2 importer - the correspondning provider was missing on the server, so the package worked locally but not remotelyy.

Comment: All the providers are available, It works fine when I run it manually.

The problem is the SQL Server credentials provided in the SSIS package are set to windows authorization and the user created it is abc\def but the SQL service agent is abc\ghi. so when we run the job it is not able to find abc\def user's credentials and returns an error that credentials not found.

Comment: According to your question, the error says "provider not registered" and not "credential not found"... anyways, we have dedicated users on the server which we can use for this kind of activity - so if you configure the job step, the drop down list shows the SA user and other users which can be used to execute the package.

Comment: in Job Step, it shows only on option "SQL Server Agent Service Account"